# Awesomium Is Not Loading In DockRight Pane When In Add-In-Express

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, awesomium

We have been experiencing problems using Awesomium in the ADX add in when it is loaded in either the DockRight or DockLeft positions, but not when it is loaded in the ReadingPaneRight (or other non dock positions).

The Awesomium browser fails to display anything and just shows a busy cursor. It also does not fire any events. It is as if it has gone into some loop during startup.

If the form region is dragged to another location (for instance to the right of the message pane) and outlook is restarted, it loads just fine and the pane can be dragged into the DockRight/Left positions.

Is this a known issue? Is there any work around?

I have also asked this question over on the ADX support forums

http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=12055&MID=61413#message61413

I did see this support issue:

http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=11542

But that seemed to be about painting, while this seems to be about loading.

Note that Awesomium does load just fine in a VSTO custom task pane (if that helps at all.)

I've created a sample project here: https://github.com/greenkiwi/AwesomiumADXDockIssue/

> This is an example ADX project running Awesomium that fails to display the browser or load anything in either the DockRight or DockLeft positions.
>
> To run this project, you must have both Add-in-express installed and Awesomium and Outlook 2007 or greater (I tested against 2010).
>
> Awesomium
>
> http://www.awesomium.com/
>
> Add-in-express
>
> http://www.add-in-express.com/
>
> Once they are installed, debug the application. The Awesomium window will open in the DockRight position, on my machine, I just get a busy cursor when ever the mouse enters the region, and the page never loads and no events get fired.
>
> If you drag the form into the reading pane area and stop and restart the project, you will see the page load as it should load. The form region can now be dragged to other locations w/o a problem, however, if it is left in the dock right or left positions and outlook is stopped and started, it will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the discussion at http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=12055.